# sed: modify function arguments

Tags: function, sed, arguments

I'm trying to write a sed command that will allow me to modify a function's arguments. The number of arguments can be variable.

If this is my function:

```
int myFunction(int arg1, int arg2, Dog arg3) {
    // function implementation
}
```

I would like to be able to perform addition operations on int arg1, int arg2, ...

Here's what I have that does not work:

```
sed -e '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\s\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+(/ , /)[\n\s]*{/ {
    # arguments should be listed here
}'
```

Any help is appreciated. Go easy on me, it's my first attempt at sed / shell scripting.

Thanks.

Comment: if it's a variable number of arguments you can't solve this with regexs alone. You will need at least a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy), or a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, `sed` is not the correct tool for this job - because of your comment about 'the number of arguments can be variable'.  If you are dealing with a fixed number of arguments of a fixed type, you can kludge your way around it, but any more general processing requires a more general processor (than `sed`).

I suggest trying a different task as your introduction to shell scripting and `sed`.

If you must do it, then maybe:

```
sed '/^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*  *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]* *([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*  *\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\) *, *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*  *\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\)[ ,)].*{/{p;a\
    return \1 + \2;
}' $file
```

That horror of a match contains the sequence `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` 6 times; it matches an identifier each time.  The segment from '`[ ,)].*{` matches a third or subsequent arguments.  The spaces in the pattern should, perhaps, be '`[<blank><tab>]`' character classes, but they're a pain to enter on StackOverflow.  The regex then matches a function definition, and captures (in the '`\(<identifier>\)`' parts the names of the two variables (`arg1` and `arg2` in your example).  The actions when this is recognized are:

1. `p` - print the line that was recognized.
2. `a` - append the following line(s) to the output; in this case, one line containing a return statement that is the sum of the two remembered argument names.  The backslash indicates that there is another line of output to append.  The braces group the operations together.

Some versions of `sed` support more powerful regular expressions than others; I'm not sure though that even GNU sed supports PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), and it would take something like PCRE to significantly reduce the the regex.

Note that this script leaves the comment line '`// function implementation`' untouched.  It's your call what you do with that.

Finally, remember that if you write more than one function to add two integers together, you are wasting code.  Therefore, this is not a plausible transformation.  Each function should do something different, somehow.  Granted, if the types are different each time, then maybe it has its uses, but even so, it would be easier to write a generator than to parse the skeleton and fill in the bits.  And that might be a good scripting exercise.

Comment: You can use `[[:blank:]]*`. Super-sed (`ssed`) supports PCREs. Also, you should point out that `sed` doesn't do multiline regex matching since the OP tried to match newlines on the LHS of a `s///`. You have to write a `sed` script using hold space and/or branching. And I think "additional" may have been intended rather than "addition".

Comment: @Dennis: POSIX `sed` does allow the `[[:blank:]]` notation - I learned `sed` before those existed, so I tend to forget them.  Your newline point only goes to emphasize that `sed` is not the right tool for this job.  And your interpretation of `addition` as `additional` is quite possibly correct - and again emphasizes that `sed` is not the tool for the job.  So, I agree with all your comments.